# How to merge a default list of Object with values from tfvars (Terraform)

Tags: terraform, hashicorp

I'm trying to achieve something with Terraform and I getting some trouble to find any solution.

I define a variable like this:

```
variable "node_pools" {
  type = list(object({
    name               = string
    location           = string
    cluster            = string
    initial_node_count = number
    tag                = string
  }))


  default = [
    {
      name               = "default-pool"
      cluster            = "cluster_name"
      location           = "usa"
      initial_node_count = 3
      tag                = "default"
  }]

}
```

Then, in my `tfvar` file, I define my `node_pools` like that:

```
node_pools = [
  {
    name           = "pool-01"
    tag            = "first-pool"

  },
  {
    name               = "pool-highmemory"
    tag                = "high-memory"
  }
]
```

Then, in my `main.tf` I try to use my `node_pools` variable but I need them filled with the default values which are not specified in the `tfvar`, like `location, cluster, etc.`.

I think I need to merge, but I don't find any way to achieve that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide your current TF code with your merge, and explain why it does not work. Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for a whole variable is only for situations where the variable isn't assigned any value at all.

If you want to specify default values for attributes within a nested object then you can use [optional object type attributes](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#optional-object-type-attributes) and specify the default values inline inside the `type` constraint, like this:

```
variable "node_pools" {
  type = list(object({
    name               = string
    location           = optional(string, "usa")
    cluster            = optional(string, "cluster_name")
    initial_node_count = optional(number, 3)
    tag                = optional(string, "default")
  }))

  default = [
    {
      name = "default-pool"
    },
  ]
}
```

Because these default values are defined directly for the nested attributes they apply separately to each element of the list of objects.

If the caller doesn't set a value for this variable at all then the single object in the default value will be expanded using the default values to produce this effective default value:

```
tolist([
  {
    name               = "default-pool"
    location           = "usa"
    cluster            = "cluster_name"
    initial_node_count = 3
    tag                = "default"
  },
])
```

With the tfvars file you showed the effective value would instead be the following:

```
tolist([
  {
    name               = "pool-01"
    location           = "usa"
    cluster            = "cluster_name"
    initial_node_count = 3
    tag                = "first-pool"
  },
  {
    name               = "pool-highmemory"
    location           = "usa"
    cluster            = "cluster_name"
    initial_node_count = 3
    tag                = "high-memory"
  },
])
```